# Time Format <Second dec> always zero in Microsoft Dynamics Navision 2009

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2009

In a table in Dynamics Navision 2009 we use a field named [Last Time Modified]. Data type is `Time` (in the database it is a DateTime). It contains values with fractions of seconds (like `13:14:15.678`).

In NAV / Connectivity Studio / Documents / Export, the fractions are not exported by default to the XML. So I created my own format (see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/format-property):

```
<Hours24,2>:<Minutes,2>:<Seconds,2><Second dec,4>
```

which results in the XML as:

```
13:14:15,000
```

The fraction part is always 0. What I need is:

```
13:14:15,678
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried to call `format` function directly from your own code? And have you tried also to call it with standard format that contains fractions of seconds like `format(“Last Modified”, 0, 2)`?

Comment: I am not allowed to access the code units, since they are maintained by a third party. At this point, the column [Format Expression] is the only thing I have.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `<Hours24>:<Minutes,2>:<Seconds,2>,<Second dec.>`?
I took standard one and changed to colon and comma in places where needed.

Comment: We do not use NAV anymore, so I cannot verify this. Maybe somebody else?